# Using variable A to control variable B

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, function, variables

I have a function called `FarmClick`, and I want it to check the current `MovieClip`'s array. For example:

```
var farmSpot1:("id",int,int);
var farmSpot2...
```

I need the `clickEvent` to capture the `MovieClips` name and check it's array for the 0th element to see whether it's empty, or not...
My code so far:

```
 public function FarmClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
        var CurrentSlot = event.currentTarget.name
            if ([event.currentTarget.name[0]] = "empty") {
            stage.addChild(menu);
            menu.x = 400;
                menu.y = 90;
            this.menu.buyCornBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buyCorn2);
        } else if (farmEmpty == true && itemSelected != "none") {
            selected();
        } else if (farmEmpty == false) {
            farmHarvest();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a minute to figure out just exactly what it was that you're asking.
So basically, your movie clip's name would be `farmSpot[someNumber]` and you have an array with the same name?

in that case, to reference the array variable, you need to use the `this` keyword.

you can add any array subscripts after you've referenced it like so:

```
private var farmSpot1:Array = ["id", int, int];

public function FarmClick(event:MouseEvent): void 
{
     if (this[event.currentTarget.name][0] == "") // wasnt sure if you meant the string "empty" or just an empty string, so i just put an empty string
     {
          // do whatevs
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, everything works well now!